Nonnegative functions with minimum constantly equal to 0
I wondered if the following statement was true:

Suppose we are given continuous functions $f_1,..., f_k: [0,a) \to [0, \infty)$ (where $a>0$) so that $f_i(0)=0$ for all $i$ and $\min \{f_1, ..., f_k\}$ is constantly equal to zero, or equivalently, for each $t\in[0,a)$ there is $i$ with $f_i(t)=0$.
Then there is $j\in \{1,..,k\}$ and $b\in (0,a)$ so that $f_j\vert_{[0,b)} \equiv 0$, i.e. $f_j(t)=0$ for all $t\in [0,b)$.

Intuitively, this feels true. But the longer I try to prove this, the more I doubt it. I aimed for an argument involving the measures of the sets $f^{-1}_i(\{0\})$. The idea was the following:
Define
\begin{equation} c_i = \inf \; \{ c: \text{There is } d>c \text{ so that } f_i\vert_{(c,d)} \equiv 0 \} \in [0,a) \cup \{\infty\}, \end{equation}
where $\infty$ stands for the case where the set above is empty. Define $c = \min \{a, c_1, ..., c_k\}$. Then I expected that the sets $S_i = \{ t<c : f_i(t)=0 \}$ would have measure zero, which would then yield a contradiction in the case $c>0$, as their union must be $[0,c)$, which has nonzero measure. So $c=0$, so $c_j=0$ for some $j$, so $f_j$ is zero on a neighborhood of $0$.
But then I remembered that there are sets of nonzero measure that contain no intervals, such as $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$.
My questions are: Is the statement above true? If yes, how can you prove it? If not, is it possible to name a counter example? Or is there just some contradictory argument involving the axiom of choice, where no concrete example can be named?
Thanks in advance :)

The statement is false already for $k=2$.
As an example, for $x>0$ define
$$f_1(x) = \max\left\{x\sin\left(\frac1x\right), 0\right\}$$
$$f_2(x) = \max\left\{-x\sin\left(\frac1x\right), 0\right\}$$
and $f_1(0) = f_2(0) = 0$.
Both functions are non-negative and continuous on $[0,\infty)$ (so they work with any desired $a > 0$).
If $x\sin\left(\frac1x\right)$ is positive, we have $f_2(x)=0$. If $x\sin\left(\frac1x\right)$ is negative, we have $f_1(x)=0$. If it is zero, then both $f_1$ and $f_2$ are zero. So $\{f_1, f_2\}$ fullfills the conditions from the statement.
But neither function is identical to zero in any interval $[0,b)$, because you can find an $r > \frac1b$ such that $\sin(r) > 0$, and so $f_1\left(\frac1r\right) > 0$ and similiarly there is an $s > \frac1b$ such that $\sin(s) < 0$, and so $f_2\left(\frac1s\right) > 0$.

Let's try looking for a counterexample with $k = 2$ (we know $k = 1$ fails, so this is the first case which has a chance of success).
We want $f_1(\{0\})$, $f_2(\{0\})$ to not contain any interval around $0$. So maybe should aim for these sets to be something like this
$$f_1^{-1}(\{0\}) = \left[\frac 12, 1\right] \cup \left[\frac 18, \frac 14\right] \cup \left[\frac 1{32}, \frac 1{16}\right] \cup \cdots$$
$$f_2^{-1}(\{0\}) = \left[\frac 14, \frac 12\right] \cup \left[\frac 1{16}, \frac 18\right] \cup \left[\frac 1{64}, \frac 1{32}\right] \cup \cdots$$
To do this, we can make each $f_i$ have a little "bump" on the region where we don't want it to be zero. This will clearly be continuous at any point away from $0$. To make it continuous at $0$, you just need to make sure that the bumps get smaller and smaller.
So this gives a countexample.
What if we try looking for any interval, instead of intervals that start at $0$?
One way to do this is to use Baire Category Theorem, which instantly answers it (and in fact even works if you have countably many functions).
